# No plugin found for prefix 'dependancy' in the current project

Tags: java, dependencies, pom.xml, dom-events

No plugin found for prefix 'dependency' in the current project
No plugin found for prefix 'dependancy' in the current project
No plugin found for prefix 'dependancy' in the current project
No plugin found for prefix 'dependancy' in the current projectNo plugin found for prefix 'dependancy' in the current project

Comment: You should give more detail about your question. This looks like you just copy-pasted the error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got a typo "depend**a**ncy".
Change to "depend**e**ncy".